# Print at least one decimal point in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to integrate a number of float variables into a printed string using %f. For most things, %.1f gets me what I need, 6 becomes 6.0 and so on, but when I need to print more than two decimals obviously it gets truncated. Problem is, I can't use %.2f because then my round numbers print two decimals when I only need a .0

Comment: I should have been more clear, I am trying to integrate a number of float variables into a printed string using %f. For most things, %.1f gets me what I need, 6 becomes 6.0 and so on, but when I need to print more than two decimals obviously it gets truncated. Problem is, I can't use %.2f because then my round numbers print two decimals when I only need a .0.

Comment: So you want 6 to become 6.0 but not 6.00? You could use `%g`, but then your `6` will be printed as `6` and not `6.0`.

Comment: @toti08 Yes, that is precisely my problem. I want it to print at least one decimal at all times, but more if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could work: you use the `.format` method and explicitly convert the argument to `float`, for example:

```
>>> a = 6
>>> print(This is a number {}'.format(float(a)))
This is a number 6.0
>>> a = 6.23
>>> print(This is a number {}'.format(float(a)))
This is a number 6.23
```